# How to write data in MySQL database without cron?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, cron

I stuck with one problem. I am creating a web based game. It's more like real time web based app. My players can build buildings. Each building have unique hash id. Builded buildings with all parameters were stored in SQL. All i want to do is to make engine that automaticaly collecting resources (gold). I dont want to use cron. I want to make that when i press "engine on" it will start to collect gold:

```
if( $sql['engine'] == 1 ){
     //do the job..
}
```

I have tried this method, but had no luck (**collect.php**):

```
if( $sql['engine'] == 1 ){
  mysql_query("UPDATE `info` SET `gold` = `gold` + 10 WHERE `building`='{$building}'");
}
```

And **index.php**:

```
function enginestat() {
    $("#EngineStatus").load("../job/collect.php?building=<?php echo $building; ?>", function () {
        setTimeout( function () {
            enginestat();
        }, 1000);
    });
}
$( function () {
    enginestat();
});
```

I believe that i am doing something wrong, but can someone tell me what i am doing wrong? I need an answer, I need detailed information. Thank you.

Comment: **WARNING**: This is terrifyingly insecure because those parameters are not [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You should **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into the query: it creates a gigantic [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used, it's being removed from PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Comment: Since you're writing a game, which can be highly competitive, you're going to be a target for hacking. Be sure do to everything by the book. A tiny mistake can be enough to crack open the entire database. If you're just getting started on your app you may want to evaluate various 
[development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) which can make implementing your design a lot easier.

Comment: Technically speaking, your `<?php echo $building; ?>"",` is outside the quotes. Actually, one quote too many. `("../job/collect.php?building=<?php echo $building; ?>",` - *my bad*.

Comment: @tadman What is the difference between a potential sql injection and the "gigantic SQL injection bug" you point out here? Does it end the life of the universe? A helpful hint does not get better by exaggeration!

Comment: @arkascha A bug that can be exploited is always gigantic. Sadly there's no such thing as a "tiny SQL injection bug". A single one is basically end-game for your server and database when there's tools that can [exploit these automatically](http://sqlmap.org/). Read any news about Sony? That could have all started because someone got sloppy and didn't escape a **single** parameter, and from there, privilege escalation took care of the rest.

Comment: @arkascha Your dismissive attitude is extremely worrying. This is not a laughing matter. Your personal information could be leaked from a reckless disregard for proper programming practices.

Comment: @tadman The matter not, though it only risks the database, not the system. You behavior is...

Comment: @arkascha Read the features of that injection tool very, very carefully. It can execute arbitrary system commands. If you think this stops at the database, you are severely misinformed.

Comment: Beside the point of SQL injection, I think letting a client-side script determine how often your players get gold pretty much means they can have as much gold as they want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing could be broken down into a series of smaller steps. For example, if you collect X gold per hour, all you need to do when the person loads the page the next time is compute the differential gold they have accumulated.

Each time they check, record the poll time in the database. The next time they check compute the differential seconds and interpolate how much to pay out. At 100 per hour, that works out to 100 / 3600 per second. You can obviously round up to avoid showing the incremental values.

Comment: i thought about that, but i want to show ppl live gold collecting per s. for example i want to make ppl to see how is growing gold amount.

Comment: If you want to show this figure incrementing in "real time" then use ajax calls

Comment: @MarkBaker easy to talk.. i am new in ajax. could you show me examlpe? I wrote something like ajax/jquery..

Comment: @user3292639 You're making an AJAX call in your example. Just make sure that each time that page is polled you only pay out the amount since the last poll time. That might be zero if they're checking more than once per second.

Comment: @tadman thanks man! i will try it tomorrow.. can i contact you somehow? via skype maybe?

Comment: If you need on-demand support for this, you could try [HackHands](https://hackhands.com/). It's cheaper than my hourly rate.